# Find vectors forming a closed path

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, problem-solving

Let us consider a function $f: [a,b]\times S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $a,b$ are reals and $S^3$ is the sphere defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$.

I will denote $\vec{u} = (k,\vec{r})$ where $k\in [a,b]$ and $\vec{r} = (x,y,z,w)\in S^3$. Then, the function $f$ has two-components

$$
\vec{f}(\vec{u}) = \left( f_1(\vec{u}),f_2(\vec{u})\right)
$$

In am interested in the following (very general) problem.

Find if it exists a set of positive coefficients $\{a_k>0\}$ such that

$$
\sum_n a_n\, \vec{f}(\vec{u}_n) =0.
$$

For $n>2$ this is equivalent of asking if I can find a closed path built with "vectors" proportionals to $\vec{f}(\vec{u}_n)$.

Are these kind of problems studied somewhere?

Take for example the functions

$f_1(\vec{u}) = 9 (144 - 528 k + 532 k^2 - 200 k^3 + 25 k^4) w^2 - 60 x^2 + 10 (8 - 12 k + 3 k^2) y^2 + 900 z^2 - 1872 k z^2 + 1188 k^2 z^2 - 360 k^3 z^2 + 45 k^4 z^2\\
f_2(\vec{u}) = 12 (17 - 24 k + 6 k^2) w^2 - 15 x^2 + 5 (8 - 12 k + 3 k^2) y^2 + 9 (17 - 24 k + 6 k^2) z^2$

Comment: So the functions you have in mind are of the form $A(k)\cdot\vec r$ where $A(k)$ is $4\times2$-matrix with polynomial entries?

Comment: Actually the coordinates in $\vec{r}$ that appear in the functions are quadratic. So I would say, the functions I am interested are of the form $\vec{r}^T A(k) \vec{r}$ where $A(k)$ is a 4x4 matrix

Comment: Each $f(u_n)$ is a two-dimensional vector.  Three or more of them are linearly dependent ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe the vectors are not generals, but they have a specific functional form. For example, it is not obvious that a sum of vectors can be expressed as the  same vector evaluated in a third point; namely it is not obvious that there it exists a point $\vec{u}_3$ such that $\vec{f}(u_1) + \vec{f}(u_2) = \vec{f}(u_3)$

Comment: Not he sum, but a linear combination, as the three vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: I am saying that there exist surely a third vector $\vec{v}$ such that $\vec{f}(u_1)+\vec{f}(u_2)+\vec{v}=0$ but it is not obvious at all that this vector lies on the image of the function $\vec{f}$. So, even if you find $\vec{v}$, the problem is not resolved